# Aginity puredata error with REGEXP_EXTRACT

Tags: sql, regex, netezza, aginity

I have the following error when executing the REG_EXTRACT I do not know what the error will be.

You can also help me by indicating what this sentence is for, which I don't understand very well.

I run this on aginity puredata version 4.9.1.2686

Thanks for your help.

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT('HELLO','(?&lt;=EN_LA":")(.*?)"')
```

Error

```
ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  0 : Regex: pos(5) syntax error in subpattern name (missing terminator)
Culprit Pattern: (?&lt;=EN_LA":")(.*?)"
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to use `'(?<=EN_LA":")[^"]+'`?

Comment: I don’t think Aginity has anything to do with your error… and I agree with Wiktor’s comment above… what is your desired output?